# Proof verification on a theorem on quadratic surds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

The question is:[image]

Proof:
Case 1: $A, B, C, D$ all are non- zero
$$\sqrt A+ \sqrt B=\sqrt C+\sqrt D \Rightarrow A+B+2 \sqrt AB= C+D+2 \sqrt CD \Rightarrow A+B=C+D$$ and $AB=CD$
or $ \sqrt AB$ and $ \sqrt CD$ are rational.
If the former case happens then,
Let $AB=CD=\alpha$
${\frac \alpha B}+B={\frac \alpha C}+C$
This would give rise to two possiblities:

(A)$C=B$  and thus $A=D$

(B)${\frac \alpha {BC} }=1$

For (B), we can immediately deduce that $B=D$ and $A=C$.
If the latter case is applied, then
$\sqrt AB=r$ and $\sqrt CD=s$ for some rational $r$ and $s$.
It is not hard to see that all the surds $\sqrt A, \sqrt B, \sqrt C, \sqrt D$ are similiar if $\sqrt A$ is irrational. If $\sqrt A$ is rational, then all of the surds are rational.
Case 2: If any one of them is $0$
without loss of generality, let $A=0$
$$B=C+D+2\sqrt CD$$
This leads to the fact that $\sqrt CD$ is rational.
If $\sqrt CD=0$, then (a), (b) in the question will be satisfied. But if $\sqrt CD$ is not $0$, then (c), (d) get satisfied.
Please verify the proof. Could you help me get the shorter proof?

Comment: Case 1's latter case in which $\sqrt AB$ and $\sqrt CD$ are rational